# Python shell.sendkeys slowly

Tags: python

I have this code here that is meant to type these keys into a website that simulates a piano.

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
Shell.SendKeys("kfa kfa kf kfa kfa kf lfs lfs lfz fsl fsl fkf a")
```

It works fine but it sends all the keys at once. Is there a way to make the program pause after every key?

Answer (score 0):

Use the python `sleep` Function

```
Shell.SendKeys("k")
sleep(1)
Shell.SendKeys("f")
sleep(1)
Shell.SendKeys("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending each key separately. It would look something like this:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("kfa")
time.sleep(1)
shell.SendKeys("kfa").... //etc`
```

The time of `sleep()` is in seconds, so feel free to adjust the timing however you like!